# How do I make my toggle button scroll up slightly when I scroll down the page?

Tags: html, css, scroll, sidebar, vertical-scrolling

I am making a website that will have multiple pages and each page will potentially be long so at first I wanted a way to have access to menus and stuff in a sidebar. But then I changed my nav so that it isn't fixed any more and so scrolling down the page now looks weird because the toggle is quite low down the page (due to being below the nav at the top of the page). Sow how do I get the toggle, sidebar and content to scroll up to the top of the page and then have both the toggle and sidebar then become fixed as the content side is being scrolled?.

It may be a simple solution but I cant think of how to do it and the only solution I could find was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WaypointArts/pn37C/), which actually looks quite good but is a bit too much for something so little right?

This is what I have at the moment

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#A,
#B {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 700ms;
}
#A {
  top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: orange;
}
#B {
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: green;
}
/*Hide the checkbox*/

#toggle {
  display: none;
}
label {
  position: relative;
  /*Set the left position to the same as the sidebar */
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 700ms;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  background: orange;
}
/* Initial sidebar state */

#toggle ~ #A {
  left: 0;
}
/*move both containers on toggle*/

#toggle:checked ~ #A,
#toggle:checked ~ #B {
  left: -200px;
}
/*move label to follow sidebar animation*/

#toggle:checked,
#toggle:checked ~ label {
  left: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="A"></div>
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle">menu</label>
<div id="B"></div>
```

Comment: Why cant your sidebar be fixed?

Comment: I understand your question, but why don't you try Bootstrap for HTML. This is very easy to write and understand instead of hard coding everything. Look here for [Bootstrap Nav-bar](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_navigation.asp) this saves a lot of your time and gives a great look to your page.

Comment: Try using jquery here. Use the scrollTop function to find how much of content is scrolled and then check if your scroll is beyond height + position.top of toggle. If it is, use css ({'position':'fixed';'top':0}) on toggle and sidebar. Play around a bit. I am on phone so it's hard to type the answer on it.

Comment: Can't you make the toggle menu position:fixed?

Comment: I can't make it fixed because then it would be really far down the page and it doesn't look the best

Comment: and I'm not using bootstrap because I don't know how to use it and the same for jquery, but if it comes to it I might have to learn jquery I just don't really have the time to